# What is an idiomatic way of saying 'Straitness is in the heart'?

Tags: idiom-requests

*Straitness is in the heart*, or *The narrows is in the heart* is a translation from the Arabic الضيق في القلوب.

It means the "strait" is not real, it's just in our hearts. It means that we have to make more room in our hearts to accept and love people, that our hearts are the ones that need widening and accepting.

> Teacher: Adam you come sit next to Steve.
>   Steve: There's no space, it's already strait here with barely any room for elbow space.
>   Teacher: Straitness is in the heart.

It's meaning has evolved to say that one is most welcome.

> A: Please come in.
>   B: No thank you, it's all right. It looks too crowded in there; I don't want to be more strain.
>   A: Strainness and straitness is in the heart.

Any similar sayings/idioms?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @user151577 You'd better edit your question soon.

Comment: @Zaid from the tag I assume they want to know how to phrase this sentiment in English.

Comment: A strait is a narrow body of water connecting two wider bodies.  Do you mean straight?

Comment: @user151577 "Where there's room in the heart, there's room in the house [...even for a mouse]"

Answer (score 2):

Consider a Danish proverb brought to the US by [early immigrants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Americans), [*Where there's room in the heart, there's room in the house*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&pg=RA1-PA477&lpg=RA1-PA477&dq=%22room+in+the+heart+there+is+room%22&source=bl&ots=1GCt961p4q&sig=kq0lqfTMrFsZc4RDlruTlKRbc4s&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo_9P5tvzJAhWGuhoKHZ4DAg44ChDoAQgdMAI#v=onepage&q=%22room%20in%20the%20heart%20there%20is%20room%22&f=false) (or *home*). [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=what+stronger+breastplate+than+a+heart+untainted&oq=%22what+stronger%22+%22than+a+he&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.0.0i22i30l3.2609.21351.0.27031.29.28.1.0.0.0.1880.8657.0j8j11j4j7-1j1.25.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..5.24.8085.0.jkRyaIkPz84#q=%22room+in+the+heart+there%27s+room+in+the%22)

> *From Nebraska stem such proverbs and sayings as "Where there's room in the heart, there's room in the house," "Don't holler before you're hurt," and "As safe as a cow in the stockyards."*

[Encyclopedia of the Great Plains](http://plainshumanities.unl.edu/encyclopedia/doc/egp.fol.036)

> A: *Please, come in*.
>
> B: *No, thank you. It's all right*. *It looks too crowded in there, I don't want to be more strain*.
>
> A: *Where there's room in the heart, there's room in the house. Come on in*.

Answer (score 0):

**When there’s a will, there’s a way.**

A proverb that fits your context.